# Cannot set tableHeaderView height to the same as the table view frame height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a `tableHeaderView` that is the same height as the table view. Consider the following code:

```
private func setupViews() {

    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ])

    // Call async else frame size will be incorrect
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.makeTableHeaderView()
    }
}


private func makeTableHeaderView() -> UIView {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: tableView.bounds.height))
    tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
    headerView.backgroundColor = .red
    return headerView
}
```

This results in extra space at the bottom of the table and allows the table to scroll a little (not the image is the table scrolled):

[image]

Why is there extra height here? I want it to be exactly the same size as the table view frame.

Any tips or pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Call `self.makeTableHeaderView` in async block is not a correct way to get right frame of the table view because a result size of the table view will get only after viewDidLayoutSubviews method (this method may be called many times).
A good place for update a size of the header view is [viewWillTransition(to:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition), but there you should use [systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)](http://systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)) to calculate a result size of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to respect the safe-area, or you'll get inconsistent results between devices.

Second, you'll want to set your header view's height *after* the table has been laid out. You'll probably also want to change it if/when the table frame changes (such as on device rotation).

So, implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` in your controller like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        
        // height of the table view
        let tableFrame = tableView.frame
        // current frame of the header view
        var headerFrame = headerView.frame
        
        //Comparison necessary to avoid infinite loop
        if tableFrame.size.height != headerFrame.size.height {
            // table view frame height has changed
            headerFrame.size.height = tableFrame.size.height
            headerView.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
class BigHeaderViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
            
            // height of the table view
            let tableFrame = tableView.frame
            // current frame of the header view
            var headerFrame = headerView.frame
            
            //Comparison necessary to avoid infinite loop
            if tableFrame.size.height != headerFrame.size.height {
                // table view frame height has changed
                headerFrame.size.height = tableFrame.size.height
                headerView.frame = headerFrame
                tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        tableView.tableHeaderView = makeTableHeaderView()

        tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
    
    private func makeTableHeaderView() -> UIView {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = .red
        return headerView
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried setting the height in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` like this and I'm still getting the wrong height

Comment: @Kex - you need to be a little more clear about *"the wrong height"*. The code example I posted does what you asked in your question. Did you try running this code by itself?